# How do I get the channel a message was sent in?

Tags: discord.py

I have been trying and making and building some channel lockdown commands, but they all didn't work. So far, I only have a lockdown command which locks a specific, fixed channel (code down below). So could someone tell me how to make a lockdown command which locks the channel the command was sent in?

```
@bot.command(aliases=['sd'])
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def shutdown(ctx):
    """Shuts down #bank"""
    intro = bot.get_channel(768788764008251436)
    await intro.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You retrieve the channel a message was sent in by calling.

```
intro = ctx.channel
```

Comment: @235baron remember to accept answers which have solved your problem by clicking on the check mark next to the answer. This way others finding this question can know what worked for you.

Comment: I know, but stackoverflow only allows me to in another 7 minutes