# How do I make a lockdown command for a specified role?

Tags: discord.py

You may have seen my previous question ([How do I make a lockdown command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65608857/how-do-i-make-a-lockdown-command)), where I asked about how to lockdown specified channel. But that command only locked down the @ everyone role. My server has millions of roles and channels made for other roles, so I want to know how to change `ctx.guild.default_role` to something where you specify the role and the channel locks down for that role. Current command:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def lockdown(self, ctx):
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
        await ctx.send(ctx.channel.mention + " ***is now in lockdown.***")
```

Comment: Please provide link to previous question.

Comment: @AdnanAhmed I did so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the role as an argument

```py
async def lockdown(self, ctx, role: discord.Role): # `RoleConverter` will automatically convert it to a `discord.Role` instance
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False)
    await ctx.send(ctx.channel.mention + " ***is now in lockdown.***")
```

You can invoke it by mentioning the role, by putting the role ID or simply by passing the name of the role

Comment: It doesn't seems to lock the channel. I tested it with a special role on my alt and my alt was still able to type in the channel. There were no admin perms on the alt.

Comment: That's weird, are you sure the hierarchy of the roles is correct?

Comment: Yes. The bot's role is at the top of the roles list.

Comment: Ah, now it works properly. As it seems, if even one of the roles have the perms ticked, then he is allowed to send messages.